# Prove by Combinatorial Argument that $\binom{n}{k}= \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

This is a question from my first proofs homework and I am confused about the combinatorial argument aspect. I already did the algebraic proof. I think I am supposed to put into words what both sides represent? So the LHS would be the number of ways of picking a committee of $k$ members from $n$ people, or number of subsets of size $k$ from a total of $n$, but I don't know how to articulate what is happening on the RHS.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a hint.  Try multiplying through by $k$, so it's at least obvious that both sides are integers.  Then what you want to show is that $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.  The LHS is now the number of ways to select a committee of $k$ members from $n$ people along with a decision of which of those $k$ will be chairperson.  Can you reinterpret this to get the RHS?.

Comment: Okay, that helped a lot. So then the RHS would be the number of ways of selecting the chairperson first, and then forming the committee of k-1 from a total of n-1 people, because we assume the chairperson is a part of the committee?

Comment: Exactly right.  I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Your expression can be rewritten as 
$$
\binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{1}=\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
Hence LHS can be interpreted as the number of ways to select $k$ unique items out of $n$ AND then one out of these $k$. Then RHS is the number of ways to select one item out of $n$ AND then $k-1$ out of the remaining $n-1$.

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that this argument works more generally, in the sense that you can replace all the $1$'s by $m$ for any $m\leq k$.

Comment: A generalization of this idea leads to [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient).

Comment: +1 smart visualisation

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a finite set with $n$ elements with $n \ge 1$ and let $k$ satisfy $1 \le k \le n$.

Recall the concept of $k$-combinations (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)) so that the number of subsets of $X$ with $k$ elements can be written as $C(n,k)$.

With

$$ \mathcal{P_k} (X) = \{ A \subset X \mid |A| = k\}$$

we can write $|\mathcal{P_k} (X)| = C(n,k)$.

Select any element $x' \in X$ and let $X' = X \setminus \{x'\}$.

Define

$\; \mathcal L = \{(A,a) \mid A \in \mathcal{P_k} (X) \, \land \, a \in A \}$

and observe that $|\mathcal L| = k \times C(n,k)$.

Define

$\; \mathcal R = \{(A,a) \mid A \in \mathcal{P_{k-1}} (X') \, \land \, a \in X \}$

and observe that $|\mathcal R| = n \times C(n-1,k-1)$.

Define the function $\alpha:\mathcal L \to \mathcal R$ by

$\quad \alpha(A,a)={\begin{cases}(A\setminus\{a\},a),&{\text{if }}x'\notin A\\(A\setminus\{x'\},a),&{\text{if }}x' \in A\end{cases}}$

Define the function $\beta:\mathcal R \to \mathcal L$ by

$\quad \beta(B,b)={\begin{cases}(B \cup \{b\},b),&{\text{if }}b \notin B\\(B \cup \{x'\},b),&{\text{if }} b \in B\end{cases}}$

It is immediately seen that
$\;(\beta \circ \alpha)(A,a) = (A,a)$
and
$\;(\alpha \circ \beta)(B,b) = (B,b)$
and the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection between the two sides as follows:

Consider a general permutation of the form $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, e.g $\text{oxoxxxox}$ from $\binom83$.

If we add another $\text{o}$, then there are $9$ places we can do this, i.e. multiply by $n$.

Also, there are $k$ 'pre-patterns' that lead to a given pattern. In the example,

- $\text{xoxxxox}$
- $\text{oxxxxox}$
- $\text{oxoxxxx}$

all yield $\text{oxoxxxox}$ on the next step (this takes $\binom72$ to $\binom83$), and so we divide by $k$.